# Observables Filter observable and map to different Observable Object: Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have this sample code:

```
    return this.users$
    .pipe(
            map((users: Array<User>) =>
                users.filter((user: User) =>
                    user.profile_id === id && user.isAdmin()
                )
            )
        );
```

I have  this interface:

```
export interface DialogSelectList {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

I want to map the result of filter into a **Observable< Array< DialogSelectList > >**
instead of **Observable< Array < User > >**

Comment: How do you create `DialogSelectList` from `User`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in same map or add another map

```
    return this.users$
    .pipe(
            map((users: Array<User>) =>
                users.filter((user: User) =>
                    user.profile_id === id && user.isAdmin()
                )
            ),
            map((users: Array<User>) => users.map(u => ({id: u.profile_id, name: u.name})) 
        );
```

Comment: how can i return inside the first map?

Comment: the part `user.profile_id === id && user.isAdmin()` implicitly returns. you need not return by addilng a return statement explicitly. You can check out implicit returns in arrow functions.

Comment: @FabioSantos chain `.map(u => ({id: u.profile_id, name: u.name}))` after your filter

Comment: @saivishnutammineni if you want to return an object instead of `u => { return {xx:xx} }` you can simply can `u => ({xx:xx})` and no return is needed

Comment: @Reza yes. but i was talking about the implicit return inside filter

Comment: @saivishnutammineni also that is not needed, if it's only one statement and you want to return that value , you can skip `{ return ` and `}`

Comment: @yeah i called it as implicit return (skipping {return}).